# Protocol Buffers - RPC

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm trying to have a messaging service(over TCPIP) between windows on PC(running C# app) and linux on an SoC board(running C++ app). I went through Google's protocol buffers and thought that I can serialize the structure (data struct) into a buffer and write this buffer over sockets(saw an example too).

My question, is there another way to do this? What does protocol buffer-RPC do? I went through their documentation but they don't specify on how to do it with TCPIP. Maybe someone has examples for this or detailed documentation?

Thank you,
Karthik.

Comment: Protocol buffers are just the data format. You can send them however you want. Or you can use [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io), Google's RPC system.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: I went through the example they have for gRPC. Its for localhost, I want it over TCPIP. There documentation doesn't cover on how to do this or I might have totally missed it. Do you have any examples or documentation on how to use gRPC? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have anything other than that link. But I'm pretty sure you should just be able to replace "localhost" with an IP address or host name and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

> My question, is there another way to do this?

There are many ways to do this. Google Protocol Buffers is library for cross-platform object serialization. You can share this serialized data in many different ways. **My recommendation for you is using ZMQ ([ZMQ GUIDE](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all)) which is perfectly suited for applications like yours.**

I have a similar use case to you. I wrote Linux C++ ZMQ server on Raspberry Pi and Python ZMQ client dedicated for telemetry and remote management purposes. This library is efficient, lightweight, works perfectly with Google Protocol Buffers and has binding to all major programming languages. If you decide to use this library do not hesitate to ask me about working code example.

Comment: We would like to have an RPC to avoid having a byte decode for all the functions we have. That's the reason I was looking for how gRPC works. We haven't decided what to use yet.

Comment: I understand your concerns. I'm aware that protocol buffers are shipped with RPC support however they are better ways to implement packet oriented transport. One of the ways is ZMQ networking library. It is efficient, lightweight yet powerful tool. It supports not only trivial client-server communication like RPC model but many others communication patters like publish-subscribe (pattern to asynchronously notify many clients registered to some event) push-pull (pattern to distribute tasks to workers) and many many others. I really encourage you to get along with this library.

Answer (score 0):

See if the Google Developers page on how the protocol buffers wire format is encoded helps with your question: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding